# TaskCanceledException running large query against Spanner using .NET Nuget packages

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Running a simple query like a select against a small table and I get results back; executing the same code using a more complex query and it errors out with a Task Canceled Exception.

```
        var executeSqlRequest = service.Projects.Instances.Databases.Sessions.ExecuteStreamingSql(
            new Google.Apis.Spanner.v1.Data.ExecuteSqlRequest()
                { Sql = sql_text, QueryMode= "NORMAL" },
            session);

        PartialResultSet resultSet = await executeSqlRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

*more info from debugging through the lib - looks like the socket was disposed while still in use and accessing it caused the task to be cancelled:*

> System.ObjectDisposedException occurred Message: Exception thrown:
>   'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll Additional information:
>   Cannot access a disposed object.
>
> System.IO.IOException occurred Message: Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll Additional information: Unable
>   to read data from the transport connection: Cannot access a disposed
>   object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'..

*from client code debugging:*

> A task was canceled. {   "ClassName":
>   "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException",   "Message": "A task
>   was canceled.",   "Data": null,   "InnerException": null,   "HelpURL":
>   null,   "StackTraceString": "   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteUnparsedAsync>d__30.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.d__27.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__26.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   Discovery.ListAPIs.Program.d__10.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Users\Dave\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\SpannerConsoleApp\SpannerConsoleApp\Program.cs:line
>   257",   "RemoteStackTraceString": null,   "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
>   "ExceptionMethod": "8\nThrowForNonSuccess\nmscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter\nVoid
>   ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)",   "HResult":
>   -2146233029,   "Source": "mscorlib",   "WatsonBuckets": null }---

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the REST-based APIs to talk to Spanner. While I'd expect it to work, we're focusing on the gRPC-based API. That's not ready yet, because we're working on a layer over the top of the raw RPCs... the intention is that users shouldn't need to use the low-level abstraction.

Comment: So what is the current approved way to access Spanner programmatically, preferably via .NET or python? Or should I wait for the gRPC based API framework to be done?  Thanks

Comment: I don't know about Python, but yes, for C# I would wait for the ADO.NET abstraction to be done. Keep an eye on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet...

Comment: @dr3x as Jon says, the preferred way to use Cloud Spanner is to use the client libraries. We have released libraries for Java, Go, Node.js, Python, and PHP here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/libraries

C# and Ruby are coming. These client libraries are all gRPC based.

Comment: Yes not able to execute the query via the Python lib either; issue writeup here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/975  There I am getting StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED